# jQuery How to return mouse position with a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I've made simple function to get the mouse location on a page.  I want to make it simpler so I can just pass a variable to another function.  Right now, I have this:

```
$(document).on('mousemove', world, function(e){
    var loc = function(){
        this.x = function(){
            return e.pageX - $(world).offset().left;
        }
        this.y = function(){
            return (e.pageY - $(world).offset().top)*(-1);
        }
    }
    console.log(loc.x, loc.y)
});
```

The console.log just returns undefined.  Is there a way to do this globally so I can use a variable such as `loc.x` to pass into a function?

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/f1z4czem/ If so just make an object (scope it properly to your application, not global) and just keep reassigning the properties of the object.

Comment: @DennisMartinez You got it!  Would you mind posting that bit of code as an answer so I can accept and up vote it?

Comment: @DennisMartinez add [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js) to your jsFiddle's "External Resources" when using the `console` and impress everyone. :P

Comment: You assign a function to `loc`, but you never call it. Since it assigns to `this`, it should be called with `something = new loc()`. And then you assign functions to `x` and `y`, so they have to be called as `something.x()` and `something.y()`.

Comment: @keyboardSmasher hah! i didn't know you could do that. thanks for the tip. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to create an object to the scope of your application. (Putting it to a global level may cause namespace clashes.)

```
var loc = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
};
```

Then just keep reassigning the properties of your object in your event, in this case it's when you move the mouse to keep track of where the mouse location is.

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function (e) {
    loc.x = e.pageX;
    loc.y = e.pageY;
    console.log(loc.x, loc.y);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f1z4czem/)

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm advocating it, but here's how you would do it in the way you tried:

```
$(document).on('mousemove', "#world", function(e){
    var self = this
    var loc = function(){
        this.x = function(){
            return e.pageX - $(self).offset().left;
        }
        this.y = function(){
            return (e.pageY - $(self).offset().top)*(-1);
        }
    }
    var thing = new loc();
    console.log(thing.x(), thing.y())
});
```

You have to call `loc()` to get the object. And then you have to call `thing.x()` and `thing.y()` to execute those functions and get the values.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/f1z4czem/7/)

Comment: Thank you for this example and correcting my mistake, I think it will help others when they need this specific answer.  Dennis showed me a new way of doing it and it is working out well.